# Could not determine java version from '10.0.2' while starting Grails 3.3.8 application

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I just installed Grails 3.3.8 but when I'm trying to run a sample application I got the below error :

```
Error |
Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.
at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:78)
at org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ConnectorServices.checkJavaVersion(ConnectorServices.java:66)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ConnectorServices.close(ConnectorServices.java:53)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultGradleConnector.close(DefaultGradleConnector.java:57)
at org.grails.cli.gradle.cache.CachedGradleOperation.call(CachedGradleOperation.groovy:78)
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.populateContextLoader(GrailsCli.groovy:526)
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:509)
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:307)
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:270)
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)

Error |
 Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my java version is  *java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17*, Windows 10 64bit, the *JAVA_HOME* was already set and using intellj

Comment: The old gradle version that get's used there (3.5.x) does not work with Java 10.  AFAIK 4.7 introduced official support.

Comment: I installed the latest GRADLE 4.10.1 and configured the IntelliJ to use it but still having the same error

Comment: You have to do that in your project.  Grails integrates with gradle.  But i have my strongest doubts, that it will work.  There are lots of changes between 3.5 and 4.10

Comment: @cfrick any recommendations for doing this?

Comment: Changing the Gradle version is not going to help. Grails 3.3.8 does not support Java 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails 3.3.8 does not support Java 10.  You will have to use Java 7 or Java 8 if you want to use Grails 3.3.8.

Comment: Can we assume, Grails 3 dies with JDK8?

Comment: "Can we assume, Grails 3 dies with JDK8?" - No.  Grails 3 works fine with JDK8.

Comment: I meant, since JDK8s EOL is determined, can we assume, that the Grails 3 line lives and dies with the support for it?  And that a Grails supporting JDK11 will most likely be of the "4" line (e.g. mn based)?

Comment: We don't drop support for Grails when the relevant JDKs EOL.  We have a lot of customers still using Grails 2, for example, and we support them.  Grails 4 is the first version of Grails which will support a JDK greater than 8.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I downgrade to Java 8 and the application started successfully

Comment: @SShehab That makes sense.  I am glad you got it working!

Comment: @JeffScottBrown It's nice that _you_ support it, but if people have to move away from the Java 8 JVM because of its EOL, what are they supposed to do?

Comment: "...but if people have to move away from the Java 8 JVM because of its EOL, what are they supposed to do?" - I am not sure what you are really looking for there.  If people have to move away from java 8, then they have to move away from java 8.  This is really no different then when folks had to move away from java 5 or any other version.  We will continue to evolve our frameworks to support future versions of java, including post java 8 versions.